# Moving a KineticJS line with a transition

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs, transition

I am using the fantastic KineticJS JavaScript framework to do some illustrations.

I have a number of Tweens in my illustrations for some funky transitions.

My problem is that i am am trying to move a Kinetic.Line() object across the illustration smoothly.

The DOCS for KineticJS say you can use tweens to transition "Any numeric property of a Shape". I know that the Points in the `Kinetic.Line()` object is not numeric, its an object property.
Is there a way to access the `kLine_MovingLine.attrs.points[0].x` to be used in the tween.

My lines are very simple. They only have two points (From and To points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still tween a line like you would tween any shape by changing it's properties!

```
var line = new Kinetic.Line({
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  points: [0, 0, 50, 50],
  stroke: '#FF0000'
});

var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
  node: line,
  duration: 1,
  x: 400,
  y: 30,
  points: [100, 50, 25, 0]
});
```

In the above example, I used the tween to change the x, y and points properties. Check this fiddle and see that it works as expected: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/MjLdT/)

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I had tried this before but with v4.5.3 of Kenetic and the line was just disappearing. I though i was doing something wrong.
I tried your example that used the latest version and it all worked :)